# Perform right click on element using RSelenium

Tags: r, firefox, rselenium

I'm trying to learn RSelenium in R using Firefox. I can already find the desired element and move mouse over it, but when I try to right-click it, it ends up being left-clicked instead.

I tried reading the documentation (`?remoteDriver` and `?webElement` are really helpful), but `webElement` class has only `clickElement` method, which is left-click by default and has no arguments, and `remoteDriver` has `click` method with `buttonId` argument, where 2 or 'RIGHT' should be right-click where the mouse is currently located, but for some reason it does not work as I intend and performs left-click instead.

Please note that I'm aware of existing questions about the same thing in JavaScript, Selenium, using PhantomJS and so on, I have read them and they did not help me. If you feel like I missed something though, feel free to give me a link.

It is also not my goal to just open the page in new tab, this is just an example of an action that could be performed by right-clicking an element.

The smallest reproducible example I could come up with is this:

```
library(RSelenium)
rd <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox')
rdc <- rd$client
rdc$navigate('http://google.com/ncr')
elem <- rdc$findElement('partial link','About')
rdc$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = elem)
# the following should open contextual menu, but enters the "About" page instead
rdc$click(buttonId = 'RIGHT')
# if the above line worked correctly, the following should open the "About" page in new tab
# rdc$sendKeysToActiveElement(list(key='down_arrow',key='enter'))
# rd$server$stop() # close everything and free the port
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I deleted my 'idea' answer as it is not working.  After navigating to a text input box `webElem$sendKeysToActiveElement(list(key = 'shift', 'r'))` will work as a key chord (typing `R`), but as you note this does not work with shift+f10 key chord.  And 'menu' key does not appear to be mapped.  And I can't get `click(2)` to work either.  Hopefully moving this question back to unanswered will get you some more traffic and a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will wonder, but the only change you should do in your script is the following:

```
rdc$click(buttonId = 2)
```

It will trigger a right click in the middle of element .